# Object property returning undefined after mounting component and setState

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a callback from axios.get to set the state of a React component. The data property of the response contains an array of objects which I use to set state.

When I log the state property to the console there are no issues and I can see the array of objects. However if I try to log one of those objects individually I get the error:

Cannot read property '0' of null at ResponsiveTable.render

Below is the code for my component:

```
class ResponsiveTable extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            returnedQuery: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/latestLeads')
          .then((response) => {
              this.setState({
                  returnedQuery: response.data
              });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
    }

    render() {

        console.log(this.state.returnedQuery[0]);

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `render` is called before `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure at first render your returnedQuery is null so you are getting this error.

If you want to use `this.state.returnedQuery[0]` check if it's exist and it's length > 0:

```
render() {
        if (this.state.returnedQuery && this.state.returnedQuery.lenth > 0){ 
                return (
                    <div>
                        {this.state.returnedQuery.map(...)}
                    </div>
                );
        } else {
            return <div>loading data...</div>
        }
    }
```

Comment: I should have explained the scenario a bit better the plan is to use the .map method to iterate through the returned array to render populated table cells within rows. So I need the objects inside the array's properties to be available within the render function

Comment: @NiallFaucher, see, at first render will work `else` because `this.state.returnedQuery === null` from the constructor. Then, after the axios query `setState` will fire redner second time but `this.state.returnedQuery === [{},{},{}]` and will work the first part of the if statment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
class ResponsiveTable extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            returnedQuery: null
        };
        this.getData();
    }

    getData = () => {
         axios.get('/api/latestLeads')
          .then((response) => {
              this.setState({
                  returnedQuery: response.data
              }, () => {console.log(this.state.returnedQuery);}); //What does this console.log() say?
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
    }

    render() {

        console.log(this.state.returnedQuery[0]);

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: In response to your question the console.log(); returns the array but using console.log(this.state.returnedQuery[0]); in the render func still causes an error I think this is explained by Andrew point about first render. I need to find a way of having first render wait until the response.data is ready

Comment: But why? The moment you change the state, react re-renders. What are you trying to do with `returnedQuery[0]`? I wouldn't go against react and try forcing `render()` to wait or smth. like this

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which was quite similar to Andrew's above, I used the component's internal state to determine whether the axios.get method had returned. Below is the working code, I'm now able to access elements within the returned array and their properties.

```
class ResponsiveTable extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            returnedQuery: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        const self = this;

        // let returnedQuery;
        axios.get('/api/latestLeads')
          .then((response) => {
              self.setState({
                  returnedQuery: response.data
              });
              console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
              <h1>{'This will always render'}</h1>
              { this.state && this.state.returnedQuery &&
              <div>{this.state.returnedQuery[0].email}</div>
              }
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do this: `const self = this;` that's 1997 code. Instead use an arrow function to bind the function to your component:

`myFunction = () => {...}` you are now able to access "this" within your component in the right scope. The react functions like `componentDidiMount`are usually already bound. Try to do this instead: 
`this.setState(...)`